# Marshmallow Parent Schema - How to share a validation decorator between child schemas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, marshmallow

I have a parent marshmallow schema "ParentSchema" and 2 nested children schemas "ChildSchema1" and "ChildSchema2". Both nested children schemas are taking advantage of the [@validates_schema](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/api_reference.html#module-marshmallow.decorators) decorator for field validation from marshmallow. They look like this:

**ParenSchema.py**

```
from marshmallow import Schema, fields
from schemas.childSchema1 import ChildSchema1
from schemas.childSchema2 import ChildSchema2

    class ParentSchema(Schema):
        child1 = fields.Nested(ChildSchema1)
        child2 = fields.Nested(ChildSchema2)
        foo = fields.String()
        bar = fields.String()
```

**ChildSchema1.py**

```
from marshmallow import Schema, pprint, post_load
from marshmallow import fields, ValidationError, validates, validates_schema

class ChildSchema1(Schema):
    field1 = fields.String()
    field2 = fields.String()
    common_field = fields.String()

    @validates("common_field")
    def validate_common_field(self, common_field):
        try:
            # Validation logic
        except:
            raise ValidationError('common_field is not valid')
```

**ChildSchema2.py**

```
from marshmallow import Schema, pprint, post_load
from marshmallow import fields, ValidationError, validates, validates_schema

class ChildSchema2(Schema):
    common_field = fields.String()
    field3 = fields.String()

    @validates("common_field")
    def validate_common_field(self, common_field):
        try:
            # Exact Same Validation logic as common_field from ChildSchema1
        except:
            raise ValidationError('common_field is not valid')
```

Given that both ChildSchema1 and ChildSchema2 have a field of the same name, with the same validator function, I'd love to follow [DRY Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and pull that function out to ParentSchema.py.

Answer (score 0):

A solution I found is creating a separate class to host the shared validation functions:

```
def validate_common_field(self, common_field):
    try:
        # Exact Same Validation logic as common_field from ChildSchema1
    except:
        raise ValidationError('common_field is not valid')
```

And consume that from ChildSchema1 and ChildSchema2 by removing the @validates decorator and using the `validate` parameter in the schema field like this.

**ChildSchema1.py**

```
from marshmallow import Schema, pprint, post_load
from marshmallow import fields, ValidationError, validates, validates_schema
from validators import *

class ChildSchema1(Schema):
    field1 = fields.String()
    field2 = fields.String()
    common_field = fields.String(validate=validate_common_field)
```

**validators.py**
    from marshmallow import ValidationError, validates

```
def validate_common_field(self, common_field):
        try:
            # Validation logic
        except:
            raise ValidationError('common_field is not valid')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach with a separate function is fine.

If the common field is shared by both children, you could also use inheritance to reflect that and factorize the field and the logic.

```
class ChildSchema(Schema):
    common_field = fields.String()

    @validates("common_field")
    def validate_common_field(self, common_field):
        try:
            # Validation logic
        except:
            raise ValidationError('common_field is not valid')

class ChildSchema1(ChildSchema):
    field1 = fields.String()
    field2 = fields.String()

class ChildSchema2(ChildSchema):
    field3 = fields.String()
```